# What is the proper way of running a shell command in a 2nd remote terminal in VSCode from python script

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am developing a Python script remotely over SSH on a Raspberry Pi with VSCode.

Within the script I want to run a command in a detached subprocess, with

`subprocess.Popen('command')`

The command produces output on stdout, which I would like to display in a second terminal for debugging purposes.

Which python command do I use the best.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You could either use the `logging` module to write that information to a file, or go with something like this with the `.call()` function:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, run

cmd = [command, "-arg1", "-arg2"]
result = run(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
print(result.stdout)
print(result.stderr)
```

this prints the output.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I also found an option with "GNU screen". There is a plug-in for VSCode (multiple-terminals). If someone could give me some hints I would appreciate it.  I will try tomorrow and will give feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to go is to use libtmux (https://libtmux.git-pull.com/quickstart.html#quickstart and https://libtmux.git-pull.com/api.html)

You can actually send and receive line(s) in multiple parallel, independent terminal sessions!

For my need to talk to a websocket server while checking the state of the server, this is the perfect solution for me. It is running in VSCode for debugging purposes during coding as well as in a conventional SSH session after deployment for fixing problems remotely.

Best regards,
LeFish